# Why does it seem necessary to rotate transformation matrix for mapping coordinates with scikit image?

Tags: python, computer-vision, linear-algebra, scikit-image

I have a set of points that are effectively 3 vertices of a 45-45-90 right triangle and some other points, `a`, that should map to them.

```py
import numpy as np

points = np.array([
    ( 90, 416),
    (398, 390),
    (374,  84)
])

a = np.array([
    (0, 1),  # maps to (90, 416)
    (1, 1),  # maps to (398, 390)
    (1, 0)   # maps to (374, 84)
])
```

I want to find the [similarity transformation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.SimilarityTransform) that properly maps `a` to `points`.

```py
from skimage import transform

# transformation that makes sense to me
T1 = transform.estimate_transform(
    ttype="similarity",
    src=a,
    dst=points
)

# invert the rotation for no reason
# other than to show that it works
T2 = transform.SimilarityTransform(
    scale=T1.scale,
    rotation=-T1.rotation,
    translation=T1.translation
)

# apply transformations via matrix multiplication
a_T1 = a @ T1.params[:2, :2] + T1.params[:2, 2]
a_T2 = a @ T2.params[:2, :2] + T2.params[:2, 2]
```

Why is it that `T2` (where I just inverted the rotation for no real reason other than I eventually found out that it works) yields the better mapping? Or am I making a dumb mistake in my implementation?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not you. There's lots of different conventions around transformation matrices and it just so happens that

- skimage uses `(M @ x.T).T` as the convention
- In this case, `T2.params[:2, :2]` is equal to `T1.params[:2, :2].T` (This is not generally true, if you have skew.)

But, I personally am always confused by the conventions here myself. To figure it out I had to know that skimage transforms have a [`__call__`](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/628adaaccd15341ab69d77365b1de2f84e10a926/skimage/transform/_geometric.py#L695-L709) method, so you can just apply them with `T1(a)`, which gives the correct results. So now it was just a matter of looking at the source code and seeing that it calls [`_apply_mat`](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/628adaaccd15341ab69d77365b1de2f84e10a926/skimage/transform/_geometric.py#L673-L687), which looks like this:

```py
    def _apply_mat(self, coords, matrix):
        ndim = matrix.shape[0] - 1
        coords = np.array(coords, copy=False, ndmin=2)

        src = np.concatenate([coords, np.ones((coords.shape[0], 1))], axis=1)
        dst = src @ matrix.T

        # below, we will divide by the last dimension of the homogeneous
        # coordinate matrix. In order to avoid division by zero,
        # we replace exact zeros in this column with a very small number.
        dst[dst[:, ndim] == 0, ndim] = np.finfo(float).eps
        # rescale to homogeneous coordinates
        dst[:, :ndim] /= dst[:, ndim : ndim + 1]

        return dst[:, :ndim]
```

For your transform (which is affine), this is essentially equivalent to `(T1.params[:2, :2] @ a.T).T + T1.params[:2, 2]`, which is equal to `a @ T1.params[:2, :2].T + T1.params[:2, 2]`, again, the transpose of what you were computing and equal to `a @ T2.params[:2, :2] + T2.params[:2, 2]`.

Even though it's confusing to have multiple conventions out there, I hope this clarifies why things were looking wonky!

Comment: thanks @Juan! definitely not the most intuitive convention indeed